# SharedPreferences сохранение\проверка\считываение числового значения

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Недавно начал заниматься в Android Studio, постоянно обращаюсь для решения вопросов на этот ресурс, однако сейчас я ответа - не нашел.

**Задача** - переписать значение "1" в `SharedPreferences`, доступное для проверки и считывания на всех активностях. Изначальное значение равно "0", значение меняется после нажатия на кнопку (которая потом становиться недоступной).

**Проблема** - После нажатия на кнопку она исчезает, однако, при возвращении на ту же активность опять становиться доступной.
Возможно я неверно задал условия или не верно сделал `SharedPreferences`.
Код дан ниже:

```
public class Luis_Room_Activity_act1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sPrefLKC = getSharedPreferences("val", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int val = sPrefLKC.getInt("val", 0);
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.luis_room_act1_layout);
```

---

```
public void onClickButton3(View view) {
    if (getSharedPreferences("val", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) == getSharedPreferences("val", 0)) {
        SharedPreferences sPrefLCK = getSharedPreferences("val", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefLCK.edit();
        editor.putInt("val", 1);
        editor.apply();

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton3);
        txt.setText(R.string.textViewEmpty);
        view.setEnabled(false);

    } else {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton3);
        txt.setText(R.string.textViewEmpty);
        view.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде много непонятных действий, которые стоит проигнорировать. В качестве триггера рациональнее использовать булеву переменную, что избавит от проверок в `if`:

```
public class LuisRoomActivityAct1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sPrefLKC = getSharedPreferences("val", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isEnabled = sPrefLKC.getBoolean("val", true);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.luis_room_act1_layout);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); // кнопка, на которою нажимать для скрытия.
        btn.setEnabled(isEnabled); // восстанавливаем значение
    }

    public void onClickButton3(View view) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefLCK.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("val", false);
        editor.apply();

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewButton3);
        txt.setText(R.string.textViewEmpty);
        view.setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

PS: В Java принято именовать классы с большой буквы в CamalCase стиле, а не через прочерки, как у вас.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onClickButton3(View view) {
    if (sPrefLKC.getInt("val", 0) == 0) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefLKC.edit();
        editor.putInt("val", 1);
        editor.apply();
        view.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
       //...
    }
}
```

Когда вы возвращаетесь на предыдущий активити, кнопка доступна снова, потому что `setEnabled(false)` совершается ТОЛЬКО при нажатии на кнопку, соответственно вам нужно проверять содержимое `Preferences` ещё и в `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.luis_room_act1_layout);

    if (sPrefLKC.getInt("val", 0) == 1) {
       Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
       button3.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!